# How to keep alive an IBM MQ connection that expires instead of disconnecting

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

We have a basic adapter => channel => adapter pattern with `int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter` and `int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter`. The connectionFactory is a `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory` (code below). It gets message from a MQSeries Broker (9+) toward another MQSeries Broker (6+).

This bridge works well with most our recipients, but one of them encounters a problem. When the bridge isn't active for a while the connection becomes "invalid" and once a new message arrives the bridge fails sending it. According to me, the connectionFactory's default behavior is to reconnect as soon at it detects the outbound has disconnected. Here, instead of detecting a "disconnection", it tries to use the previous connection and fails:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue....  
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'.
```

I am not skilled with networking / sockets (and so on), but it sounds like something expired on the recipient side (with no disconnection notification). It sounds like that a "keepalive" option on the connection would help here, but I was not able to find such a mecanism in Spring Integration JMS and/or IBM MQ classes.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can perform such a keepalive from Spring Integration side? Or otherwise an idea about why this connection expires without notification?

```xml
<beans>
    <int:channel id="channelMQ_MQ" ></int:channel>

    <!-- Source : MQseries -->
    <!-- ... --> 
                                    

    <!-- Destination MQ_SERIES      -->
        <!- ... -->
    <bean id="jmsQueueOut" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue" depends-on="jmsConnectionFactory">
        ...
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory2" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="queueManager" value="..." />
        <property name="connectionNameList" value="..." />
        <property name="channel" value="..." />
        <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory_cred2"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory2" />
        <property name="username" value="..."/> 
        <property name="password" value="..."/> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="connectionFactoryCaching2"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory_cred2" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="..." />
    </bean>
    
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="channelMQ_MQ" 
                                      id="jmsOut" 
                                      destination="jmsQueueOut" 
                                      connection-factory="connectionFactoryCaching2" 
                                      delivery-persistent="true" 
                                      explicit-qos-enabled="true" 
                                      session-transacted="true" >
    </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

**Edit 1** :

- MQSeries Version 6
- IBM Mq classes : 9.1.5
- Spring Integration : 5.5.13
- MQSeries Setting :

  - HBINT : 60
  - KAINT : 120
  - SHARECNV => does not exist on version 6

Comment: What version of IBM MQ are your jar files from?   Ask the MQ admin what the HBINT (heart beat interval) and SHARECNV (shared conversations) are set to on the SVRCONN you connect to.

Comment: @JoshMc IBM Mq is version 9.1.5.0. HBINT is set to 60. SHARECNV does not exist yet (it looks like it was introduced in V 7+)

Comment: Anything 9.0 or less is no longer supported.  V6 has been out of support for almost 10 years.  Heart beating improved in v7.0 for clients.   Likely you have a firewall or other network device in your path that is timing out the convection because of lack of traffic.   Moving to a supported version of MQ will improve this for you since it will guarantee bidirectional traffic at least every 60 seconds.

Comment: @JoshMc I wish I could.... Obviously, everyone would benefit from this update, but we do not choose our recipents. The bridge purpose is to allow any kind of recipients, regardless of their broker's version. That's why my first feeling was that we should add a keepalive from the bridge side in order to solve this pb

Comment: Are you getting from a queue or putting?

Comment: both, but the problem occurs when putting

Comment: What does your get logic look like? How frequently do you put? Does the problem happen when you have not put for a period of time?  If yes then how long before you see an issue?

Comment: The frequency is uneven. It's a low rate bridge (less than 1k message / day), with close to zero activity during the night. And the problem does occur after a period of inactivity (exactly 1h, which sounds like some -not-found- config). The issue is seen immediately because the bridge is used in a pseudo-synchronous way (I know it's an anti-pattern here....) : as soon as a new message arrives, the bridge fails sending it, thus restarting the bridge...

Comment: What does your get logic look like?  Are you doing a get with unlimited wait or gets every so often?

Comment: The get is (already) sort-of unlimitedely waiting : it's a message driven inbound adapter. It's actually not really "waiting", but will send message to the output as soon as a message is sent to the inbound queue. The inbound will fail and the bridge restart if the inbound connexion fails (so far, it's working well from the inbound side)

Comment: Are your using a spring default message listener or a spring simple message listener?  Either way,  given you are connecting to a v6 queue manager it must be doing a polling meaning it is getting with a certain wait time and then trying again,  with the default message listener it is only 1 second default receive timeout, this would mean that your connection would have frequent activity and would explain why you do not have an issue.   Given that your volume of messages is low you could change your put to do a connect, open, put, close,  disconnect every message which would then not timeout.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to have your PUT periodically send a no op message to keep the connection alive when there is no other traffic, the other side would need to know to ignore those messages.   Ultimately the v7 enhanced bidirectional heart beats would solve this for you,  but as you said you have no control over the queue manger you connect with.

Comment: We are using the DefaultListener, with a receiveTimeout of 3s. Unfortunately, the exchange rate is uneven : low most of the time, but since it's used in a pseudo-synchronous way, every delay may break the pattern when the rate is temporarily high (if reconnections are too long and/or occur too often). THe other solution (a message-based ping), would be a solution, indeed. Not sure it will be accepted on the recipient side, but so far it sounds last the least worst solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took us a little while to find the trick, but we ended up finding the suited solution....

You need to set it up on both system and application sides:

(within *docker-compose*, you need to use the "systctls clause)

**System :**

```
  - net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=30
  - net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=2
  - net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60
```

**Application**

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.KeepAlive","YES");
```

(there are various ways to set up this system variable. This is just one of them, as a matter of exemple)